# How can I randomly choose a point from a set with Julia lang?

Tags: set, julia

I have set of points defined by inequalities

f.e `0<x<3`, `0<y<3` and `x^2+y^2>1`,

How can I randomly choose a point from this set?

Comment: Something is wrong in the question - if `x>0` and `y>0` then `x^2+y^2>0` so the last condition can be ignored. Can you please double check what you want? The simplest general approach for similar problems is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling, but maybe for your specific problem something better can be proposed.

Comment: I'm sorry,
of course `x^2+y^2>R^2, where f.e 'R = 1'
I want randomly choose a point from this set with [Julia language](https://julialang.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rejection sampling, e.g.:

```
function myrand(R)
    while true
        x, y = 3rand(), 3rand() # now x∈[0,3[ and y∈[0,3[
        x^2+y^2>R^2 && return (x,y)
    end
end
```

Of course you should make sure that `R^2<18` as otherwise you will get an infinite loop. The function is more expensive (takes more time to finish) the closer `R` is to this boundary.

If you wanted to improve the speed of it and `R>3` (e.g. when you are very close to the boundary) then you can sample `x` and `y` from the interval `[sqrt(R^2-9),3]` by rescaling `rand()` result appropriately. The reason is that you know that if `x` or `y` is less or equal than `sqrt(R^2-9)` you will reject such a sample for sure (effectively you sample from a smaller square).